# Three.js rotate camera local coord system based on lookAt vector

Tags: camera, three.js, coordinate-systems

It appears that the camera in three.js is oriented on a coordinate system that is orthogonal to the global coordinate system.  Is it possible to rotate the camera about its local coordinate system defined by its lookAt vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
camera.rotateY( angle );
```

Comment: I can see that is not super intuitive though... `camera.rotation.y` vs `camera.rotateY()`.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem.  So what is the difference then between rotation.XX vs rotateXX()

Comment: rotation is in the parent's space. rotate* are helpers to rotate the object based on its current rotation.